# WatchKit NSUserDefaults and NSKeyedUnarchiver issue

Tags: nsuserdefaults, watchkit, nskeyedunarchiver

In my project I have a custom object called Country, which implements NSCoding

The code is shared across iphone and watch app by reference. Both app are in the same app group.

In my iPhone app I'm using NSUserDefaults to story a Country object, from watch app I'm reading the same object with following code:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.my.group")
if let data = defaults?.objectForKey("country") as? NSData {
    if let country = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? Country {
        println("done")
    }
}
```

This code in iPhone app works perfectly and the country variable is correctly created, in the Watch app it is throwing an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (Country)'
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem, this helped me: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1093079#1093079

Comment: Link does not work (anymore). Please include at least the most necessary steps in your answer!

Comment: @Tjeerd : I am facing same issue, link does not work.